# How do I find the bijection from this powerset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to show that there is a bijection from  $\mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$ to $(X \to \mathcal{P}(Y))$ and prove the opposite relationship.

That is, show that $\mathcal{P}(X \times Y) \cong(X \to \mathcal{P}(Y))$ and $ (X \to \mathcal{P}(Y)) \cong \mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$. I know some relationships like $\mathcal{P}(X) = (X \implies [2])$ (and there are many more) but I can't seem to link it to the bijection relationships as required.

Comment: Given $S\subset X\times  Y$ define $f_S(x)=\{y\in Y:(x,y)\in S\}$.

Comment: Unfortunately the way the topic was taught meant that I didn't learn the meaning of all the symbols I'm looking at, since this was extra content. Rather, I was only taught some rules like how these equations can be manipulated just like algebra. Beyond that, I've no understanding of the content and originally wanted to just find an "algebraic" way of showing this relation, just like in elementary algebra. Could you explain how these relationships work?

Comment: To a set-theorist  a function $f:X\to Y$ is just  a certain kind of subset of $X\times Y$ (so $ f$ is its graph).  So  the  identity map from $\{f:X\to Y\}$  into $P(X\times Y)$ is an injection.,,,, The  mapping $\psi(S)=f_S$ given in the comment above by David C. Ulllrich is an injection from $P(X\times Y)$ into $\{f:X\to Y\}.$  ...  Now apply the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem.... So for  finite or infinite cardinals $A,B$ we have $2^{(BA)}=(2^B)^A, $ as if $A,B$ were numbers.

Comment: One application is that the cardinal of the set of real sequences is the cardinal $| \Bbb R|=|P(\Bbb N)|=2^{\aleph_0}.$  A real sequence is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$ ... So $ |\{f: \Bbb N\to \Bbb R\}|=$ $|\Bbb R|^{\aleph_0}=$ $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=$ $2^{(\aleph_0\cdot \aleph_0)}=$ $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No need for CSB - the map I defined is bijective.

Comment: The notation is degenerating.   From { f | f:X -> Y } to { f:X -> Y } to  { X -> Y } to X -> Y.  The confusing 'h $\in$ X -> Y' for example.  It is like using adgetives without nouns such as 'ran a red' for 'ran a red car' or any other red thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. Yes of course.....